# Transfer data by using Apple configurator 2

Tags: ios, apple-configurator

I'd like to use Apple Configurator 2 to transfer some data to my enterprise application. Currently the device only allow to one MacBook Pro. But I have a concern what if the MacBook Pro broken? When I prepare my devices, I'm able to config it to "Allow devices to pair with other computers". But here comes a new concern. Does this mean my devices are able to connect to any Mac machines with Apple configurators installed? Then there is a security issue if this is the case. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yes" - the machines must be paired first, this is of course a security thing, there must be a bilateral pairing whereby both devices trust each other.

If you're worried about having to make your laptop available or broken, I suggest a configuration server or even a virtualised config. You can try running OSX inside virtual box or VMWare on OSX (which is legally allowed on apple hardware), in theory the host IDs will be within the virtual machine and not change as long as you launch the image.

Comment: Thanks. The virtual box could be helpful. I'm just wondering if there are something like whitelist to allow only a few computer by Apple Configurator.

Comment: The whitelist is pairing manually. to the best of my knowledge, trusted computers can't be delivered by profiles.

Comment: But how to do the pairing? I got a popup to ask me to trust the computer. Is this pairing? If it is, then it's not safe. Everybody can connect the phone to any Mac.

Comment: Each Mac  is uniquely identified and phone will ask each time a new machine is seen. The phone needs to be unlocked to trust - Also the Mac will ask permission to trust too. What’s your concern?

Comment: If I lost my phone, somebody got it and he can use Mac to pair with the phone. That means anybody who got the phone can pair with phone. Am I right?

Comment: The pairing must be done PER computer, and requires the phone to be unlocked every time. With a passcode/fingerprint lock you should be safe even if you lose your phone. Also it can be remote wiped via find my iPhone.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks.